# ¿Por que me indica error de sintaxis si esta correcta?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo un query que cuando la ejecuto, MySQL me bota el siguiente errores en las sentencias `declare` por cada variable declarada, por ejemplo:

> Error de SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE _ProductoId INT' at line 3

Y luego después de usar cada variable dice que es desconocida por ejemplo:

> Error de SQL (1193): Unknown system variable '_ProductoId'

Aqui esta el query:

```
BEGIN 

DECLARE _ProductoId INT;
DECLARE _ProductoCosto INT;
DECLARE _Cantidad INT; 
DECLARE _id INT DEFAULT 129;


    WHILE _id < 143 DO

    SET _ProductoId = SELECT Compra_ProductoId from tblcompradetalle WHERE CompraDetalleId = _id;
    SET _ProductoCosto = SELECT ProductoCosto from tblproducto WHERE ProductoId = _ProductoId;
    SET _Cantidad = SELECT CompraDetalleCantidad FROM tblcompradetalle WHERE CompraDetalleId = _id;


UPDATE tblcompradetalle SET
        compraDetalleSubtotal= (_ProductoCosto * _Cantidad),
        ProductoPrecio= _ProductoCosto
WHERE CompraDetalleId=_id;

     SET _id = _id + 1;

    END WHILE; 
 END;
```

[image: consola]

Comment: las variables se definen con un '@' al principio de su nombre

Comment: Estas tratando de crear un procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: no necesariamente, lo mas importante para mi en este caso particular es actualizar unos campos... no es una tarea que vaya a realizar varias veces. Ahora bien si se soluciona con store procedure me sirve
Por otro lado colega @RicardoPérez tengo entendido que@ se usa en sqlserver no en mysql

Answer (score 0):

hola amigo si no me equivoco es debido a que cada que pones un punto y como ";" lo toma como una sentencia aparte intenta colocar la siguiente linea al inicio 
delimiter $$ 
y en la ultima linea cambias el ";" por $$
END $$

```
delimiter $$ 
    BEGIN 

DECLARE _ProductoId INT;
DECLARE _ProductoCosto INT;
DECLARE _Cantidad INT; 
DECLARE _id INT DEFAULT 129;


    WHILE _id < 143 DO

    SET _ProductoId = SELECT Compra_ProductoId from tblcompradetalle WHERE CompraDetalleId = _id;
    SET _ProductoCosto = SELECT ProductoCosto from tblproducto WHERE ProductoId = _ProductoId;
    SET _Cantidad = SELECT CompraDetalleCantidad FROM tblcompradetalle WHERE CompraDetalleId = _id;


UPDATE tblcompradetalle SET
        compraDetalleSubtotal= (_ProductoCosto * _Cantidad),
        ProductoPrecio= _ProductoCosto
WHERE CompraDetalleId=_id;

     SET _id = _id + 1;

    END WHILE; 
 END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

QUizas hayan otras formas pero funciona como store procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE spCompraDetalle() LANGUAGE SQL NOT 
   DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER COMMENT '' BEGIN

      DECLARE _ProductoId int;
   DECLARE _ProductoCosto INT;
     DECLARE _Cantidad INT; 
     DECLARE _id INT DEFAULT 129;


    WHILE _id < 143 DO

SET _ProductoId = (SELECT Compra_ProductoId from tblcompradetalle WHERE CompraDetalleId = _id);
SET _ProductoCosto = (SELECT ProductoCosto from tblproducto WHERE ProductoId = _ProductoId);
SET _Cantidad = (SELECT CompraDetalleCantidad FROM tblcompradetalle WHERE CompraDetalleId = _id);

UPDATE tblcompradetalle 
SET compraDetalleSubtotal = (_ProductoCosto * _Cantidad), 
 CompraDetallePrecio= _ProductoCosto WHERE CompraDetalleId=_id;

SET _id = _id + 1;

  END WHILE; 
  END
```

...

```
  CALL spCompraDetalle()
```